# When I run flutter upgrade on my Mac Pc I get this error below

Tags: flutter, git, dart

When I run flutter upgrade on my Mac Pc I get this error below, Please I would appreciate a quick solution to speed up my development process. I have seen and try similar error solution online but is not working for me

```
adedoyinolanipekun@ADEDOYINs-MacBook-Pro momaspay % flutter upgrade   
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/2.8.0-3.3.pre': unable to resolve reference 'refs/tags/2.8.0-3.3.pre': Input/output error
From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
 ! [new tag]               2.8.0-3.3.pre -> 2.8.0-3.3.pre  (unable to update local ref)
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/2.8.1': unable to resolve reference 'refs/tags/2.8.1': reference broken
 ! [new tag]               2.8.1         -> 2.8.1  (unable to update local ref)
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/2.9.0-0.0.pre': unable to resolve reference 'refs/tags/2.9.0-0.0.pre': reference broken
 ! [new tag]               2.9.0-0.0.pre -> 2.9.0-0.0.pre  (unable to update local ref)
  Command: git fetch --tags
```

Flutter upgrade

I am expecting my flutter and dart sdk to be updated but I got the error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you local repo is broken, try this:

```
cd flutter
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
```

If the problem persists, it might be due to a more serious corruption issue. In this case, you might want to re-clone the Flutter repository:

```
cd ..
rm -rf flutter
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

And then add Flutter to your PATH again:

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```